# Migrating to Async: Repository

Tags: c#, repository, async-await, .net-4.5

I have a large codebase using my repositories that all implement IRespository and I'm implementing async versions of the methods:

```
T Find(id);
Task<T> FindAsync(id);
...etc...
```

There are several kinds of repository. The simplest is based on an immutable collection where the universe of entities is small enough to merit loading them all at once from the DB. This load happens the first time anyone calls any of the IRepository methods. Find(4), for example, will trigger the load if it hasn't happened already.

I've implemented this with Lazy < T >. Very handy and has been working for years.

I can't go cold-turkey on Async so I have to add Async alongside the sync versions. My problem is, I don't know which will be called first - a sync or async method on the repository.

I don't know how to declare my Lazy - if I do it as I've always done it,

```
Lazy<MyCollection<T>>
```

then loading it won't be async when FindAsync() is called first. On the other hand, if I go

```
Lazy<Task<MyCollection<T>>>
```

This would be great for FindAsync() but how will a synchronous method trigger the initial load w/o running afoul of Mr. Cleary's warnings about deadlock from calling Task.Result?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `Lazy<T>` is that there's only one factory method. What you really want is a synchronous factory method if the first call is synchronous, and an asynchronous factory method if the first call is asynchronous. `Lazy<T>` won't do that for you, and AFAIK there's nothing else built-in that offers these semantics either.

You can, however, build one yourself:

```
public sealed class SyncAsyncLazy<T>
{
  private readonly object _mutex = new object();
  private readonly Func<T> _syncFunc;
  private readonly Func<Task<T>> _asyncFunc;
  private Task<T> _task;

  public SyncAsyncLazy(Func<T> syncFunc, Func<Task<T>> asyncFunc)
  {
    _syncFunc = syncFunc;
    _asyncFunc = asyncFunc;
  }

  public T Get()
  {
    return GetAsync(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }

  public Task<T> GetAsync()
  {
    return GetAsync(false);
  }

  private Task<T> GetAsync(bool sync)
  {
    lock (_mutex)
    {
      if (_task == null)
        _task = DoGetAsync(sync);
      return _task;
    }
  }

  private async Task<T> DoGetAsync(bool sync)
  {
    return sync ? _syncFunc() : await _asyncFunc().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

Or you can just use this pattern without encapsulating it:

```
private readonly object _mutex = new object();
private Task<MyCollection<T>> _collectionTask;

private Task<MyCollection<T>> LoadCollectionAsync(bool sync)
{
  lock (_mutex)
  {
    if (_collectionTask == null)
      _collectionTask = DoLoadCollectionAsync(sync);
    return _collectionTask;
  }
}

private async Task<MyCollection<T>> DoLoadCollectionAsync(bool sync)
{
  if (sync)
    return LoadCollectionSynchronously();
  else
    return await LoadCollectionAsynchronously();
}
```

The "bool sync" pattern is one Stephen Toub showed me recently. AFAIK there's no blogs or anything about it yet.

Comment: I was hoping you'd see this and weigh in - this is really helpful, thank you! Also really enjoying your book!

Answer (score 0):

`Task`s will run only once but you can `await` on them as many times as you want and you can also call `Wait()` or `Result` on them after completed and that won't block.

Asynchronous methods are converted into a state machine that schedules the code after each `await` to run after the awaitable is completed. However, there's an optimization where if the awaitble is already completed the code runs immediately. So, awaiting on completed awaiters bears little overhead.

For those small in-memory repositories, you can return a completed `Task` using `Task.FromResult`. And you can cache any `Task` and await it any time.

Answer (score 0):

> how will a synchronous method trigger the initial load w/o running afoul of Mr. Cleary's warnings about deadlock from calling Task.Result?

You can use the synchronous version and use `Task.FromResult` to load your `Lazy<Task<MyCollection<T>>>`. If this lazily async operation is exposed to the outside, it may confuse since it will block. If this is an internal single call situation, I would go with:

```
private Lazy<Task<MyCollection<T>>> myCollection = new Lazy<Task<MyCollection<T>>>(() => 
{
     var collection = myRepo.GetCollection<T>();
     return Task.FromResult(collection);
}
```